# How to custom tooltip over bottom box not belong to chart box of high chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I wanna custom tooltip of pie chart on highchart like design, but I dont know how to do it [likes design here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2dSD.jpg)

But I just do like that [my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gdxgu.jpg)

```
My code [here][3]
```

Comment: Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/hoaitruong/LL03yb4d/1/

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set chart's container overflow attribute to `'visible'`

```
chart: {
  style: {
    overflow: 'visible'
  }
}
```

The rest is styling html inside the tooltip, e.g. like this:

```
    pointFormat: `
      <ul class='tt-list'>
        <li class='tt-item'>Last 4-Weeks (4/17 - 5/13)</li>
        <li class='tt-item'>Orders Filled: 1,183</li>
        <li class='tt-item'>Orders Cancelled: 90</li>
        <li class='tt-item'>Open Orders: 10</li>
      </ul>`
    },
```

css:

```
.tt-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}

.tt-item:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tt-item {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0
}
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/71khj4f7/

[image: tt-oiverflow]